# An unexpected error occurred. Error# 16828

Tags: air, flash-builder, flex4.6

I'm Flex developer. I'm using Flex 4.6 framework in flashbuilder 4.6 to develope an app with NativeProcess support. For this its required to package app with native installer. ie export it to exe. If app is exported to .air, it would not support extended desktop profile or NativeProcess.

Now the problem is that with adobe auto update update feature only .air file can updated and it can not update a app installed with native installer.
As i'm trying to update the installed app, it checks update, downloads app but throws erro at end: An unexpected error occurred. Error# 16828

Please Help me if anyone is having any solution.
(There is a duplicate question but it  might be in total different scenario, so please don't down rate this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Updater class doesn't support the native installer, I am facing the same issue here, and I found this [Documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/updating-air-apps-native-installer.html) that show how to deal with the native installer,

There is also this library [nativeapplicationupdater](https://code.google.com/p/nativeapplicationupdater/) explained how it works in the following [video](http://www.riaspace.com/2010/08/nativeapplicationupdater-updater-for-air-apps-packaged-with-native-installers/), It's a bit old (air 2.0), but I guess it works, haven't tested it yet.

Good luck, 
Cheers !!